# Unsure of Answer Regarding Statistical Significance and T-test

Tags: regression, self-study, statistical-significance, t-test

In the image, 
[image]

It seems like both A and C are correct.  Because the p-value is $0\lt 0.01$, it seems logical that the slope coefficient of $0.1223$ is statistically different than $0$ at the $1%$ level.  Yet I thought, since this is a linear regression, a unit increase in the odometer reading would cause an expected increase of 0.1223, the coefficient, in annual maintenance costs.

So which is correct and what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The units of the odometer is in " thousands of kilometers". So the actual increment Should be 0.1223*1000 . So i think Part C is incorrect . Because in this question they have given the units specifically.

SO the answer should be only A.

Comment: I don't believe this is a correct understanding of the units and therefore is misleading.  Consider what the question asks: does it ask about the *significance* of the slope or about *how maintenance costs relate to distance driven?*